# flatMap() collections in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In Kotlin and Scala we have `flatMap` functions which work like below:

```
val listOfMaps = listOf(
    mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to 10),
    mapOf("a" to 3, "b" to 4, "d" to 99),
)

listOfMaps.flatMap { listOf(it["a"], it["b"]) }
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What I'm looking for is the exact same function, but in Groovy:

```
[[a:1,b:2,c:10],[a:3,b:4,c:99]].flatMap { [it.a, it.b] }
```

Answer (score 7):

The function I need is present in Groovy, but its name is different - `collectMany`.

```
[[a:1,b:2,c:10],[a:3,b:4,c:99]].collectMany { [it.a, it.b] }
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```